# configure jetty in spring boot

Tags: jetty, spring-boot

I am developing a multi-module spring boot project. My project structure look like

> - myProject(parent)
> - front-end
>
>   - src/main/resources
>
>     - frontend
>
>       - index.html
> - rest
>
>   - src/main/java
>
>     - com.example
>
>       - MyWebApp.java
>     - com.example.config
>
>       - WebAppConfig.java

I am trying to configure jetty by injecting `JettyServerCustomizer` as bean in `WebAppConfig` as following

```
@Bean
public JettyServerCustomizer customizeJettyServer()
{
    return new JettyServerCustomizer()
    {

        @Override
        public void customize(final Server server)
        {
            ContextHandler frontEndContext = new ContextHandler();
            frontEndContext.setContextPath(""); //what should be here
            frontEndContext.setResourceBase("");//what should be here
            ResourceHandler frontEndResourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
            frontEndResourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
            frontEndContext.setHandler(frontEndResourceHandler);
            ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
            contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { frontEndContext});
            server.setHandler(contexts);
        }
    };
}
```

What value to set to `contextPath` and `ResourceBase` so that I could run my index.html which is in front-end module? How the url will looks like?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot can [serve static content](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) for you. Instead of trying to configure Jetty, place your static content beneath `src/main/resources/static` and they'll be loaded straight from the classpath.

Comment: That is true when you run the application using `./gradlew bootRun` but when you build a standalone jar, then how would specify location for static content because on JAR deployment, src/main/resources/static folder isn't there in your classpath?

Comment: That specific folder isn't on the classpath, but the `static` folder and its contents are as the build system includes them in the jar.